# Find the Nth term of the fibonacci sequence

Tags: c++, function, loops, input, integer

I am writing some code that uses multiple functions. One is to generate the Fibonacci sequence up to the Nth term that the user inputs. The other function is to find the largest/last number in the sequence.

I currently have the sequence printed out just fine, but my main problem is that I cannot find a way to print out the last/largest integer in the sequence.

This is the output I want to get:

```
Enter a number: 9
The series is: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 
the maximum input is 21
```

In the function to find the last number, I am unsure of where to start as I assume the printout is an integer so I can't think of a way to access the final integer.

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int printSequence(int x);
int maxInput(int n);
```

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
    cin >> x;

    printSequence(x);

    cout << maxInput(x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
int printSequence(int x)
{
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, temp = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            cout << t1 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            cout << t2 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        temp = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = temp;

        cout << temp << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return temp;
}
```

```
int maxInput(int x)
{
    x = x % 60;
    return (printSequence(x) % 10);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print `the maximum input is 21` such that 21 is the final or last item in series? am I understand well? if so you already have this as your return type from the `printSequence` function, so you can just cout<<printSequence(x); that will return 21 or you need another thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Code After Modification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

int printSequence(int x);

int maxInput(int n);

int main() {

    int x;
    cout<<"Enter an integer: "<< endl;
    cin>> x;

    int max = printSequence(x);
    // max is the last Integer in Set
    cout<<"the maximum input is: "<<max<< endl;


    return 0;
}

int printSequence(int x){

    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, temp = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i) {

        if(i == 1) {
            cout << t1 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        if(i == 2) {
            cout << t2 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        temp = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = temp;
        
        cout << temp;
        if(i!=x)cout << ", ";

    }
    cout<<endl;

    return temp;
}
```

**Description:**
You already return the last number as `temp` from the function call `printSequence` so you can use this as your final integer.

**Another Solution:**
it is better to make your `printSequence` void function to only print and at the end of the loop you can set `temp` value to a global int to use it as the max Integer/ last integer from the sequence.
Here you can use the `maxx` as your final/last variable.

**Such As:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

void printSequence(int x);
int maxx;

int main() {

    int x;
    cout<<"Enter an integer: "<< endl;
    cin>> x;
    printSequence(x);
    // max is the last Integer in Set
    cout<<"the maximum input is: "<<maxx<< endl;


    return 0;
}

void printSequence(int x){
    
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, temp = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i) {

        if(i == 1) {
            cout << t1 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        if(i == 2) {
            cout << t2 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        temp = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = temp;
        
        cout << temp;
        if(i!=x)cout << ", ";

    }
    cout<<endl;
    maxx = temp;
    
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Another Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simple method using the golden ratio, with `O(1)` time complexity for a single value, `θ(n)` time complexity for the whole sequence, and `O(1)` space complexity, storing only the last calculated value, which is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int fibonacci(int n) // find nth value in the fibonacci sequence
{
    double ratio = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2; // golden ratio
    return round(pow(ratio, n) / sqrt(5));
}

int printSequenceAndReturnMax(int x) // print the sequence and return max
{
    int value = 0;
    std::cout << "The series is: " << value << " ";
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
    {
        value = fibonacci(i);
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    return value;
}

void maxInput(int value) // pass max value as parameter
{
    std::cout << "\nThe maximum input is: " << value << "\n"; // print it
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    int max = printSequenceAndReturnMax(x); // will have the max value
    maxInput(max);
}
```

Result:

```
Enter an integer: 9
The series is: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21
The maximum input is: 21
```

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi, here is a less *awful* ;) time complexity method

Answer (score 1):

And here is a ultra fast solution with low memory footprint.

It will easily answer all your requirments. And, it is very flexible with using algorithms from the standard library.

So, we will use a compile time pre calculation of all Fibonacci numbers that fit into a 64 bit `unsigned long long` value.

But first some theory.

One important property of the Fibonacci series is that the values grow strongly exponential. So, all existing build in integer data types will overflow rather quick.

With [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula) you can calculate that the 93rd Fibonacci number is the last that will fit in a 64bit unsigned value.

Now, calculating 93 values during compilation is a really simple task. And does not produce any runtime overhead. And a memory consumption of 752 Bytes ! is totally acceptable.

We will first define the default approach for calculation a Fibonacci number as a `constexpr` function:

```
// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
```

With that, Fibonacci numbers can easily be calculated at compile time. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all Fibonacci numbers. We use also a `constexpr` and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::integer_sequence` to create a Fibonacci number for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};
```

This function will be fed with an integer sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and return a `std::array<unsigned long long, ...>` with the corresponding Fibonacci numbers.

We know that we can store maximum 93 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the integer sequence 1,2,3,4,...,92,93, like so:

```
constexpr auto generateArray() noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 93>` with the name FIB containing all Fibonacci numbers. And if we need the i'th Fibonacci number, then we can simply write `FIB[i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

I do not think that there is a faster way to calculate the n'th Fibonacci number.

Please see the complete program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// All the following will be done during compile time

// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
// We will automatically build an array of Fibonacci numberscompile time
// Generate a std::array with n elements 
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};

// Max index for Fibonaccis that for in an 64bit unsigned value (Binets formula)
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitValue = 93;

// Generate the required number of elements
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}

// This is an constexpr array of all Fibonacci numbers
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Test
int main() {

    // Print all possible Fibonacci numbers
    for (size_t i{}; i < MaxIndexFor64BitValue; ++i)

        std::cout << i << "\t--> " << FIB[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2.

Additionally compiled and tested with clang11.0 and gcc10.2

Language: C++17